# OSM import fails due to non-matching PostgreSQL version

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, nominatim

I am trying to follow the installation of Nominatim, based on http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian. The command

```
./utils/setup.php —osm-file <pbf-file> —all —osm2pgsql-cache 18000 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

returns an error: 'PostgreSQL version is not correct. Expected 9.3 found 9.4'.

How do I get this line to work with version 9.4 instead of 9.3? I checked my version of PostgreSQL and it is 9.4.3. Looking into setup.php, I find the function returning the error

```
$sVersionString = $oDB->getOne('select version()';
reg_match('#PostgreSQL ([0-9]+){.]([0-9]+)[ˆ0-9]#', $sVersionString, $aMatches);
if (CONST_Postgresql_Version != $aMatches[1].'.'.$aMatches[2])
{
    echo "ERROR: PostgreSQL version is not correct. Expected ".CONST_Postgresql_Version." found ".$aMatches[1].'.'.$aMatches[2].'\n';
    exit;
}
```

My operating system is Debian Jessie and I am using UbuntuGIS repositories, just in case this has anything todo with the error.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, when installing Nominatim a folder 'settings' is created, holding a PHP file named 'settings.php'. Within this file all sorts of constants are defined - also 'CONST_Postgresql_Version'.

Simply edit this file and change the value from 9.3 to 9.4 will overcome the initial error message.